# SPARQL INSERT query in Protege

Tags: insert, mapping, sparql, protege4

I'm trying to map my Data Properties in Protege to owl:Class with Sparql but it doesn't work. If any one has an example, please don't hesitate to give me an answer.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX myOnto: <http://imis/SNI/9.4.3#>

INSERT DATA

   { 

      ?s rdf:type owl:Class

   }

WHERE {  ?s  ?o owl:DatatypeProperty}
```

When i was running it i got this  message . Please help me to resolve this problem.

```
Error 61 Logged at Wed Oct 15 23:11:26 CEST 2014
SparqlReasonerException: org.openrdf.query.MalformedQueryException: Encountered "   "insert" "INSERT "" at line 7, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
"base" ...
"prefix" ...
"select" ...
"construct" ...
"describe" ...
"ask" ...
```

Comment: (1) It says "line 7" but INSERT is in line 1. (2) SPARQl query != SPARQl Update.  You send operations to different endpoints and/or with different content types. Your error is consistent with parsing an update as if it were a query.

Comment: thanks for your reply concerning 1) so i added the PREFIX to the Code. 2) How could i do this update?

Comment: You need to use the right APi to send the update.  Don't send it as a query.

Comment: why not and which API should i to use?

Comment: SPARQL Update is a different language to SPARQL Query.  This stops injection attacks.  You'll need to consult the documentation as to the right endpoint.